# DDD Класс-конфигуратор для загрузки параметров в конструктор сущности

Tags: c#, конструктор, параметры, ddd

**Исходные условия:**

Есть книга с заданным набором свойств. Книга является сущностью.

```
public class Book {
    public Book(BookID id, string name, string author, double price) {
        ID = id;
        SetName(name);
        SetAuthor(author);
        SetPrice(price);
    }

    public BookID ID { get; }

    public string Name  { get; private set; }

    public string Author { get; private set; }

    public double Price { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        SetName(name);
    }

    public void ChangeAuthor(string author) {
        SetAuthor(author);
    }

    public void ChangePrice(double price) {
        SetPrice(price);
    }

    private void SetName(string name) {
        if(name == null || name.Length == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Укажите название книги");
        }
    }

    private void SetAuthor(string author) {
        if(author == null || author.Length == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Укажите автора книги");
        }
    }

    private void SetPrice(double price) {
        if(price < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Стоимость книги должна быть >=0");
        }
    }
}

public class BookID {
    public int ID {get;}

    public BookID(int bookID) {
        ID = bookID;
    }
}
```

В представленном случае книга имеет всего 4 параметра:

1. Идентификатор сущности
2. Название
3. Автор
4. Цена

В таком случае удобно использовать конструктор для инициализации сущности Book.

**Ситуация**

Пусть у книги около 20 параметров. Ситуация достаточно абстрактная. В случае книги ее может и не быть. Однако подобное может встречаться при определении модели прибора и других подобных случаях.

В случае большого количества параметров я бы для удобства создал отдельный класс `BookProperties`, в котором были бы представлены свойства книги, но без гарантии их корректности. Затем экземпляр класса `BookProperties` я бы помещал в конструктор сущности Book, в которой бы осуществлялась валидация.

Ниже представлен вариант код подобного подхода. Для удобства использовано то же количество параметров, что и ранее.

```
public class Book {
    public Book(BookID id, BookProperties bookProperties) {
        ID = id;
        SetName(bookProperties.Name);
        SetAuthor(bookProperties.Author);
        SetPrice(bookProperties.Price);
    }

    public BookID ID { get; }

    public string Name  { get; private set; }

    public string Author { get; private set; }

    public double Price { get; private set; }

    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        SetName(name);
    }

    public void ChangeAuthor(string author) {
        SetAuthor(author);
    }

    public void ChangePrice(double price) {
        SetPrice(price);
    }

    private void SetName(string name) {
        if(name == null || name.Length == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Укажите название книги");
        }
    }

    private void SetAuthor(string author) {
        if(author == null || author.Length == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Укажите автора книги");
        }
    }

    private void SetPrice(double price) {
        if(price < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Стоимость книги должна быть >=0");
        }
    }
}

public class BookID {
    public int ID {get;}

    public BookID(int bookID) {
        ID = bookID;
    }
}

public class BookProperties {
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Класс `BookProperties` предназначен исключительно для удобства создания сущности Book.

**Вопрос:**

Насколько данный подход противоречит DDD и насколько данный подход корректен в целом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сущность от класса отличает два основных фактора - индивидуальность и жизненный цикл.

Чем придумывать валидацию на входе, проще сделать её на сохранении (присвоении индивидуальности на уровне БД, как пример).

Т.е. вы можете создать класс и как угодно менять его поля-свойства, но на сохранении сущности будет валидация всех введенных данных. Никакой дополнительный класс вам в таком случае не нужен.

Дополнительно, валидация на сохранении сильно помогает с жизненным циклом - почти всегда бизнес требования ограничивают переходы из одного состояния в другое.

---

UPD: Использовать дополнительный класс выглядит лишним, особенно учитывая то, что на деле изменился только код конструктора. Сам вид конструктора ДДД никак не ограничивает, можете делать как вам удобнее. Просто помните, что идея с всегда валидной сущностью важна исключительно в хранении, а в работе - часто бывает ровно наоборот и сущность может быть невалидна в конкретный момент времени в бизнес-процессе.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но мой вопрос был не про валидацию) Что касается валидации, то я не хочу отделять правила, установленные для параметров, иначе модель станет анемичной.

Comment: @Eladei в какой момент ваш класс книги станет сущностью? На мой взгляд, вопрос именно в этом. Или вы собрались хранить `BookProperties`, а оперировать классом `Book`? Но тогда вы явно нарушаете DDD в плане того что такое сущность.

Comment: Класс Book является сущностью сразу же после своего создания. BookProperties является вспомогательным классом, предназначенным исключительно для удобства инициализации сущности Book, ни более того.

Comment: @Eladei идём дальше. Хранить вы какой из классов будете? Восстанавливать класс из хранилища каким образом будете? Зачем нужен этот класс, если он на себя не берет никакую ответственность? Ваш второй пример кода стал сложнее исключительно, а упростилась только сигнатура конструктора, которая непонятно зачем нужна в таком виде.

Comment: Я Вас понял. Об этом я не подумал. В таком случае класс BookProperties действительно абсолютно лишний. Тогда вопрос, если сущность Book, извлеченная из базы данных имеет около 20 обязательных параметров (абстрактный пример), то стоит ли опасаться наличия 20 параметров в конструкторе. При этом эти 20 параметров я не могу сгруппировать в объекты-значения.

Comment: @Eladei я предлагаю пойти дальше - убрать эти свойства из конструктора. Когда вы достаете из базы - свойства у вас в сущность забиваются напрямую. Когда вы сохраняете в базу - вы валидируете заполненность и валидность полей. Не надо ничего группировать. Всё, что вы сможете сгруппировать, с приличной вероятностью окажется либо отдельной сущностью, либо дочерней сущностью, которая существует в рамках родительской, но при этом относительно самостоятельна.

Comment: Я понимаю Ваш подход, но все 20 параметров могут быть обязательны для заполнения. Без них я не имею права создавать сущность для последующей записи в базу. Валидация не является областью ответственности хранилища. Оно лишь сохраняет агрегат. Сущность сама по себе должна быть всегда валидна.

Comment: @Eladei ну создали вы валидную книгу. А потом её надо изменить по любой причине. Простые изменения вида "изменил свойство - сразу проверил валидность" вы ещё сможете поддерживать. А вот изменения когда пользователь меняет 10 свойств по очереди и сущность в промежутке между этими операциями невалидна - у вас невозможны? В целом, я понимаю что вы хотите попроще. И да, сохранение сущности всегда можно разделить на валидацию сущности и собственно сохранение в базу, но засунуть это в один метод `entity.Save()`. Более того, это вполне логично - чтобы было невозможно сохранить невалидную сущность

Comment: Я Вас понял. Я не разделял понятия валидации свойства и сущности в целом. В представленном примере сущность Book валидна, если валидны все ее свойства. Сложных зависимостей там нет. В случаях зависимости параметров Book от других агрегатов, я бы проводил дополнительную проверку, но уже вне сущности Book, а в службе. Однако в конструкторе я бы все равно оставил параметры, обязательные для создания сущности Book.

Comment: @Eladei никто не мешает вам это сделать. Уж сам конструктор никак не ограничивается идей DDD. Я просто к тому, что ваша идея создавать сразу готовые книги с заполненными обязательными свойствами - довольно спорная и может вылезти вам боком в куче мест.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за подробные объяснения. Если есть возможность, напишите, пожалуйста, мне в личном сообщении недостатки моего подхода с возможными негативными последствиями и, если есть возможность, оптимальные пути решения. Это можно будет потом оформить в виде отдельного вопроса, что принесет пользу сообществу.